# Is it possible to design the Email Templates in 3Scale?

Tags: redhat, developer-tools, 3scale

Is it possible to edit the Email templates in 3Scale to include
html tags and css for better visual?

If I want to achieve this, is there a workaround while leveraging the Email templates inside 3scale admin developer portal?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's currently not possible to add HTML tags on any email template.

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3623091